# booting on linux failed, swap and root not found

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

I have an issue booting after an upgrade.

I am using Fedora 38.

I recently updated my machine using `dnf --refresh upgrade` but unfortunately the newly kernel installed would not boot, I am getting the following error message at boot:

```
Warning: /dev/fedora/root does not exist  
Warning: /dev/fedora/swap does not exist 
Warning: /dev/fedora/usr does not exist 
Warning: /dev/mapper/fedora-root does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue. Type "journalctl" to view system logs. 
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or boot after mounting them and attach it to a bug report. 

Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue): [231.341398] dracut-initqueue[463]: Warning: Not all disks have been found. [231.341543] dracut-initqueue[463]:  Warning: You might want to regenerate your initramfs.
```

I have tried a few solutions in different forums like: `sudo dracut --regenerate-all -f && sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

But nothing has worked so far.

The issue is also that after a week with that issue, I ran the dnf upgrade again, and the last installed kernel has the same issue, meaning that I can only boot in the oldest kernel, and I am now afraid to run an update. Otherwise, I will remove the only working kernel and won't be able to use my laptop anymore.

Any idea how to fix this?